# Campaign Member on Contact Related list

Tags: relationships, campaign, campaign-member

how can I add "Campaign Member" to the Related list on the Contact object? The Campaign Member has a lookup relationship to Contact and it seems to be fine. The only object where can I show Campain Member in the related list is "Campaign". This is some kind of salesforce standard feature :)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Related List Label for CampaignMember is Campaign. This is to make it look less awkward in the UI (after all, we're showing a list of Campaigns the Lead or Contact is related to). This is indeed a standard feature of the platform.